# Checking if folder exists in directory

Tags: rust, directory

I want to know if the folder `foo` exists in my current directory, so I wrote a function to do so:

```
use std::env;
use std::fs;
use std::io;

fn does_folder_foo_exist_in_current_directory() -> Result<bool, io::Error> {
    let cur_path_buf = env::current_dir()?;
    let cur_dir = cur_path_buf.as_path();
    Ok(fs::read_dir(cur_dir)?.find(|ref x| {
        let x = x.unwrap();
        x.file_type().unwrap().is_dir() && x.file_name().to_str().unwrap() == "foo"
    }).is_some())
}
```

However, the compiler says that I cannot move out of borrowed content here: `let x = x.unwrap();`.

Why is this moving out of borrowed content since I `ref x`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ref` in patterns is used to *construct* a reference. If the pattern `x` would have type `T`, then the pattern `ref x` will have type `&T` instead. However, it's not valid to move out of a reference, so you definitely don't want to construct a reference! ([`unwrap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.unwrap) takes `self` by value, which is why the code is trying to do a move in the first place.)

Here, the type of the parameter on the closure is a reference, because that's what [`Iterator::find`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.find) wants to pass as an argument. If you want to *deconstruct* a reference, you want to use `&` instead. However, if you write the pattern `&x` here, you'll still get the error `cannot move out of borrowed content`, but this time directly on `&x`.

What can we do instead? [`DirEntry`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/fs/struct.DirEntry.html) doesn't implement `Clone`, therefore we can't clone `x` (which is an `&std::io::Result<DirEntry>`). Instead, we could turn the `&Result<DirEntry>` into a `Result<&DirEntry>`. There's a method in the standard library to do just that: [`as_ref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.as_ref).

```
fn does_folder_foo_exist_in_current_directory() -> Result<bool, io::Error> {
    let cur_path_buf = env::current_dir()?;
    let cur_dir = cur_path_buf.as_path();
    Ok(fs::read_dir(cur_dir)?.find(|x| {
        let x = x.as_ref().unwrap();
        x.file_type().unwrap().is_dir() && x.file_name().to_str().unwrap() == "foo"
    }).is_some())
}
```

By the way, instead of doing `find(...).is_some()`, you can use [`any(...)`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.any), which is shorter and perhaps slightly more efficient. `any` also passes ownership of each iterated value to the closure, so we don't actually need to use `as_ref` with it!

```
fn does_folder_foo_exist_in_current_directory() -> Result<bool, io::Error> {
    let cur_path_buf = env::current_dir()?;
    let cur_dir = cur_path_buf.as_path();
    Ok(fs::read_dir(cur_dir)?.any(|x| {
        let x = x.unwrap();
        x.file_type().unwrap().is_dir() && x.file_name().to_str().unwrap() == "foo"
    }))
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There's no reason to iterate over all the entries in a directory to check if a single item exists. Just check for the specific item:

```
use std::{env, fs, io};

fn does_folder_foo_exist_in_current_directory() -> io::Result<bool> {
    let mut path = env::current_dir()?;
    path.push("foo");
    let metadata = fs::metadata(path)?;
    Ok(metadata.is_dir())
}
```